# How do I remove a gem with all its dependencies?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, rubygems, uninstallation

I have installed a gem on my Rails application (devise). After I installed the gem, I realized that I don't need it.

I want to remove the gem, its dependencies and the files it created on my application. In other words, I want to restore the system to what it used to be before the gem. How can I do this? (I'm using Ruby on Rails 4.)

Comment: It's a carbon copy of that question, except for the version number at the end.

Comment: it is a duplicate, i had the same problem but i didnt see anyone fix the problem on that other persons question...any suggesitons?

Comment: the fourth answer should fix your issue in any case its not exactly related to rails but to ruby, also if you are using a version control system, you could just revert the changes and delete untracked files.